# Facebook Conversion Pixel vs Script tag with Async

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, asynchronous

Facebook recommends the following code be added to a webpage to allow conversion tracking. This is one of several similar "beacons" we have installed on our site. Many of them are using the "createElement" method to insert the script tag dynamically into the document model...

```
<script>
(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
_fbq.push(['track','1234567890',{'value':'10.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
```

**Question, can the code be simplified to use the following script tag...**

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js" async></script>
<script>
   window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
   _fbq.loaded = true; // This may not even be needed anymore
   _fbq.push(['track','1234567890',{'value':'10.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm only speculating, but I know a lot of sites are pretty messily organized, and snippets like this can end up being rendered repeatedly. The document.createElement technique would prevent fetching `fbds.js` more than once in that case.

Comment: True, but one should only include the script tag once.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it's awfully edge-casey to be such a common way of expressing "include this JS on your site."

Comment: I would like to know the final script. What did you end up with?